# node is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js

I am on windows 7. I downloaded node v6.2.0 via the msi.  I can run node from c:\Program Files\nodejs. However, When I try to run it from a subdirectory under Program Files\nodejs, I get the 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file error.

I have C:\Program Files\nodejs\; in both my System and User PATHS.

Is there a way to make nodejs available in subdirectories? Also can you make nodejs available to all directories and subdirectories?

Comment: If you have it as part of your PATH environment variable, it should be available pretty much everywhere. If you type `where node` from a command prompt, you should get the path to node.exe. If not, then it's not added to your `%PATH%` correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response- c:\where node yields C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

Answer (score 0):

using the installer itself does not make nodejs apply globally at least on my machine (windows 7).  Yes, it does apply nodejs to the system environment variable path and user variable path, but to make it apply globally you need to open the dos cmd and set the path c:\SET PATH=c:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%. Once I did this, node was available to all directories and subdirectories.

Comment: Please also note, I did not have this problem on my windows 7 enterprise computer at work.  Also, I have to set path (SET PATH=c\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%) everytime I want to use node in another directory or a subdirectory.

Comment: Ok, I just did a global install of the npm from a subdirectory, npm install -g and npm update -g and now my dos command reads "Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 6.2.0 (x64) and npm" . Sweet. No more having to do the SET PATH thing everytime.

Comment: the sweetness was premature. Fired dos command up again, and got the node not recognized etc etc. so i had to do SET PATH again.